# Slidetoggle script doesnt toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide, slidetoggle

I have a toggle slide which does not work. Spend hours trying/learning to edit and rewrite this thing, but somehow the visbible and inviseble slidetoggle doesnt work.

Could someone please help me with the js script: [SEE THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hartflooring1/wfJ5y/2/)

**JS:**

```
$('.header .ullie').hide();

  $('.header h2 a').click(function() {
  $(".header h2").not(this).next(".header .ullie").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).next(".header .ullie").slideToggle("slow");
  return false;
});

$('.header h3 a').click(function() {
  $(".header h3").not(this).next(".header .ullie").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).next(".header .ullie").slideToggle("slow");
  return false;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foldercontents">
<ul class="ullie">
<li class="header">
<h2><a href="javascript:void(0);">testbutton</a></h2>
<ul class="ullie">
    <li class="foldercontent">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <ul class="ullie"><li>row 1</li></ul> 
 </li></ul>
 </li>

 <!-- second, duplicated from first -->
 <li class="header">
<h2><a href="javascript:void(0);">testbutton2</a></h2>
<ul class="ullie">
    <li class="foldercontent">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <ul class="ullie"><li>row 2</li></ul> 
 </li></ul>
 </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

[SEE THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hartflooring1/wfJ5y/2/)
*ADDED JQUERY LIBRARY

Comment: Added jQuery to the fiddle, please have a look and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looking for [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/BdBJR/2/)

```
$('ul li ul').hide();

$('.header > * > a, .foldercontent > * > a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

You could also use `margin:0; padding:0;` to prevent the jumping instead of `overflow:hidden`, but that's up to you

Also note that you don't need the `<a>` tags, you could apply them to just the headers themselves if you'd like to